# groupwise max causes sql_mode error

Tags: mysql

The challenge is to select daily maximum temperature from a table along with date and time information for each.

```
SELECT datestamp, max(temp) hitemp from Weather w group by `year`, `month`, `day`;
```

This causes

> Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'Weather.datestamp' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Other similar questions propose using JOIN, but I can't see how I can use JOIN syntax because the high temperature values are not unique.

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?  so if a datestamp has 10 records on the same day 4 of which have the same tempature do you want all 4 datestamps? just one? if one which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDBMS work best on set based logic.  So think of the data in terms of two sets:

- w2: a set of data containing the max temp for a given day
- w: The universe of data containing all the measurements for a period of time

By joining these two sets we can obtain just the data from w that have the max temperature for a given day.

By using an inline view {w2} against the entire universe set {w} we can generate the max temp for each day then join back to the base set {w} to get the time information for each day's max temp.

This assumes that:

- If a max temp is on multiple records for the same date you want them all as you've not indicated how to handle ties.
- datestamp has a time component; and it is the date/time you want to see for max temp on a day.

This is what others meant by join most likely:

- date(datestamp) simply returns the date component of a date/time.
- max() returns the max temp by the group denoted (in this case date of datestamp)

.

```
SELECT datestamp, Temp
FROM weather W
INNER JOIN (SELECT date(datestamp) mDate, max(temp) as mtemp
            FROM weather
            GROUP BY  Date(DateStamp)) W2
  on W.temp = W2.mtemp
 and Date(w.Datestamp) = w2.mDate
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
MySQL doesn't support `cross apply` nor analytical functions `row_number() Over (partition by date(datestamp) order by temp desc)` which could also be used to solve this issue with likely greater performance.  SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, Postgresql all have different ways of solving this; however the above example would work on all RDBMS engines (that I can think of); yet not be the most efficient in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for this organized and thoughtful response. Identifying the assumptions was especially revealing. Works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Your sql mode is full group by. That means all the columns in select must be in the Group By clause
datestamp is in select but not in group by.
But for temp, since you are using an aggregate function MAX, it need not be in GROUP BY. 
Use datestamp in group by or change your sql mode.

The exact reason is the mysql full group by mode and the logical query execution order of statements in mysql

**Logical Order**

- FROM
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- AGGREGATIONS
- HAVING
- SELECT

So, GROUPING is done before SELECT. So, if full group by is selected, SELECT can access GROUPED and AGGREGATED columns alone.

Comment: Your explanation of the logical order of statements is helpful!